# Carousel with button controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I am working on this carousel. 
I have the carousel moving the way i want now i am trying to add some controls below it, small buttons to link with the carousel images. 
So whenever one  is active corresponding carousel is active as well. 
i am not sure why it is not working..
Any help

here is the code HTML

```
<div id="carousel">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="slider">
    <li>
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/contemporaryartgroup/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/HZ_GCC_VUE3.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_wMcqVx7UDxoNz7YGodjI7IkO7dLREESp0RHRHIGc9bsgGFTkYg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRelq6Cmc_PV3FHGS4rzISfaL8FtjTAa0w1BXu3wR6GlDR7mLTiMw">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRivHTJU30bZXeFRoyemfX5ZHrkd-iP9hAydsoZ9onvFE8cTcmS">
    </li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>                
</div>
   <div class="buttons">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // settings
    var $slider = $('.slider'); 
    var $slide = 'li';         
    var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
    var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds
    var $btn = $('.buttons');
    var $buttonanchor = 'li';

    function slides() {
        return $slider.find($slide);
    }
    slides().fadeOut();
    // set active classes
    slides().first().addClass('active');
    slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

    //set buttons
    function button() {
        return $btn.find($buttonanchor);
    }
    button().first().removeClass('btnnotactive');
    button().first().addClass('btnactive');
    button().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

    $interval = setInterval(
   function () {
    var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();      
    slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
    slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);     
    if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start
    slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
    slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');

    var $j = $btn.find($buttonanchor + '.btnnotactive').index();
    button().eq($j).removeClass('.btnactive');
    if (button().length == $j + 1) $j = -1;
    button().eq($j + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);        
    button().eq($j + 1).addClass('btnnotactive');
}
, $transition_time + $time_between_slides
 );

});
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
#carousel
{
    min-width: 255px;
    min-height: 290px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider
{
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 580px; /* Update to your slider width */
    height: 250px; /* Update to your slider height */
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider li
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.buttons
{
    /*padding:0 0 5px 0;*/

}

.buttons li
{
    display: inline;
 background-image: url("http://www.iconmay.com/thumbnails/detail/3/violet%20button%20violet%20dot%20circle%20blank%20empty%20violet%20button%20icon.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.btnactive
{
    background:url(http://www.iconmay.com/thumbnails/detail/3/green%20button%20green%20dot%20circle%20blank%20empty%20green%20button%20icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

here is the fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/wjstowL1/13/

Comment: Not really clear as to what you're trying to do. You want controls that change the images? The "so whenever one is active corresponding carousel is active as well" part is where you lose me. Also - the buttons themselves are not visible in your jsfiddle.

Comment: as in a normal carousel where you have small buttons at the bottom, that are linked with the carousel images. so when first image is displayed then the first button is active and other buttons looks in active. when second image is displayed then the second button looks active. This is what i am trying  http://www.blackninja.com.br/ as in the above website. there are small controls at the bottom of the image. I am trying to move the controls along with the image

Comment: If you have visible buttons in that jsfiddle, I must be blind. I see them in your code, but I'm also seeing a 0 height :|

Comment: yeah i don't see them either i added min-height and min-width still i don't see them

Comment: Your HTML is not valid and may not render properly across different browsers. You have list elements wrapped with divs. Please correct your HTML and use `ol`, `ul`, or `menu` tags for wrapping `li` elements. https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/li

Comment: Hmm, you may want to have another look. Nothing within the buttons have any heights or widths set. Also - you've got what appears to be four buttons (or `li` elements). What exactly do you intend for these to do other than go left or right in the carousel?

Comment: I have added images now. so by default the dots are green and as the carousel moves the dots are supposed to be red.

Comment: I have fixed this https://jsfiddle.net/wjstowL1/80/ however i am not able to add the answer, i always get error